# Centos7: Closed the port but it still shows as listening

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld, port

I am using CentOS7. I have closed the port using the below command:

**firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --remove-port=9200/tcp**

**firewall-cmd --reload**

While executing the command, it also gives me a warning that port is not enabled.

But when I run the below command, it still shows that the port is LISTENING.

**netstat -lntu | grep 9200**

Is it ok to let this be as it is or is it risky from security point of view?

[image]

Comment: If you don't need anything to connect via that port, then stop whatever is listening on it.

Comment: The listening of a port would be handled by some process that is running.  Take a look at the output of `netstat -lnp |grep :9200` and stop/kill the process it is associated with to close the port.